# How I can show sanity images in next13? when i wanna show images from Sanity I get error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I want to use Sanity in my react app to show images and other fileds, I already used Sanity in the prior project, and now I am working on a new project but I like to use Sanity content from previous project in React/ next 13, I installed Sanity , Now I am able to fetch data like "Title" and " Message " in my solution page, however when I want to show Images I get this error :
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: (0 , *shared_Image__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.urlFor) is not a function

This is the content of Solution.jsx :
`

```
import {urlFor} from '../shared/Image'
import Image from 'next/image'
const ItSolutions = async ({ solutions }) => {

    return (
        <div className="text-center mt-24 text-slate-800 ">
            <h1 className="font-bold text-md text-orange-600 ">WHAT WE PROVIDE
            </h1>
            <h1 className="font-bold text-navy-900  text-4xl pt-5">IT Solutions
            </h1>
            <div className={main}>
                {solutions.map(solution => <div className={card}>
                        <Image
                            src={urlFor(solution.image).width(200).url()}

                            className="w-full h-full mx-auto object-cover rounded "
                            alt="member"
                            fill
                        />   
                    </div>
</div>)
                }
            </div>

        </div>

    )

}

export default ItSolutions
```

`

And this is the content of Sanity.config :
`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'sanity'

import { deskTool } from 'sanity/desk'
import { visionTool } from '@sanity/vision'

export default defineConfig({
  name: 'default',
  title: 'Sanity Project',

  projectId: 'q8l0xi0c',
  dataset: 'production',


  plugins: [deskTool(), visionTool()],

 
})
`
```

And this the content of next.config:
`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true }
    return config
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        //hostname: 'samirarahimi.blob.core.windows.net',
        hostname: 'cdn.sanity.io',
      },
    ],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
`
```

And this the content of Shared/Image :
`

```
'use client'


import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'
import sanityConfig from 'sanity.config'

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(sanityConfig)

function urlFor(source) {
  return builder.image(source)
}
export default urlFor
`
```

Please help me to be able to show images

Answer (score 0):

you can use
`"imageUrl": image.asset->url`

an example of my GROQ query:

> *[_type == "game"] {
> images[]{
> alt,
> "imageUrl": image.asset->url,
> },
> }

If you still have doubts check the docs:
https://www.sanity.io/docs/presenting-images